# How to configure multiple project in Team Build 2015

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

How to configure multiple project in Team Build 2015 (using the new task based workflow, not the old XAML builds).

Right now I see only one solution can be configured for Visual Studio build task.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily add more than one build task that explicitly calls a single solution. That will also allow you to control the order that they get built.

[image]

Just select "Visual Studio Build" from the sea list. This works in Visual Studio Online and TFS 2015.

Comment: I am looking for same feature as  in on-prem

Comment: Visual Studio Build is a build task. It exists in on-prem and in VSO.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned there are multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. Add multiple "Build with MsBuild" or "Build with Visual Studio" tasks. Let each task build a specific solution by entering the full path to the solution/
2. Use the wildcard solution to find all solutions `**/*.sln` will build all solutions in the workspace.

   - You can use a workspace cloaking rule if you're using TFVC for source control to exclude one of your solution files from the workspace, that way it won't be downloaded from sourcecontrol and won't be built.
3. Use `;` to combine multiple search patterns: `**/abc.sln;**/xyz.sln`
4. Create a custom msbuild file (e.g. `buildprojects.proj`) which in turns invokes the msbuild to build each solution you wan to build. Configure the task in the workflow to call teh `.proj` file instead of the specific solutions.

Comment: `;` doesn't work for me either.  I was so hopeful!  `,` also doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the `;` behavior has changed with the conversion to typescript. I wonder if it does support the more advanced minimatch syntax now...

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a pattern. The default for the Visual Studio template is **/*.sln, which will recursively match on all .sln files in the repository/workspace.

Comment: If My solution have different naming convention Say Abc.Sln ,CBD.sln and EDF.sln and i want only two out of them to build.

Comment: Have you tried creating a dirs.proj file and providing that to the build definition, instead of the .sln? dirs.proj can contain any projects that you want the system to build. You can find more details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx