# How to pass MSBuild arguments for mutliple projects in TFS Build definition

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am trying to pass different MSBuild arguments for two projects in TFS build definition.

I am building a single solution with two projects in it. I am able to pass MSBuild arguments without specifying a projects and it's working. Both projects are building correctly. Now, I want to pass MSBuild arguments separately to both projects because i have different arguments value for both project. I am not able to do that.

If I pass MSBuild arguments as below, common for both project, it's working both project is building correctly.

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release
>   /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web
>   Site";DefaultPackageFileName=API.zip
>   /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)"

If i pass MSBuild arguments separate for both projects,

> **/t:Project1** /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web
>   Site";**DefaultPackageFileName=API.zip**
>   /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)"
>   **/t:Project2** /p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release
>   /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web
>   Site";**DefaultPackageFileName=WEB.zip**
>   /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)"

I am only looking for a change in package name based on project as you can see above. for project1 i want API.zip, for project2 i want WEB.zip. I tried to pass it few different ways, it didn't work.

With above agruments i am getting output for both project with same package name and it's WEB.zip. I don't know why. it's building both project but names are same.

I found similar questions [specify project file of a solution using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915636/specify-project-file-of-a-solution-using-msbuild),  but it doesn't specify how to pass separate MSBuild agruments to mutliple projects.

Comment: If you don't find a solution I guess a workaround is to just build the two projects seperately?

Comment: Which build are you using? XAML (2010 and later) or vNext (2015 and later)?

Comment: vNext build definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using vNext build, you could build the two projects separately by adding multiple VS build tasks.

[image]

For more details you could take a look at below two questions:

- [How to configure multiple project in Team Build 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244196/how-to-configure-multiple-project-in-team-build-2015)
- [Build one web project from a Solution with multiple web projects in Visual Studio Online Build Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957748/build-one-web-project-from-a-solution-with-multiple-web-projects-in-visual-studi)

Comment: Yes, it's best solution. Thank you